# Could not load file or assembly Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions

Tags: .net-core, msbuild, nuget, azure-functions, visual-studio-2019

I'm using VS2019 Pro v16.3.5

I have a solution containing an Azure functions project which references several class library projects.

The top-level project fails to compile with the following error:

> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly
>   'Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions, Version=2.2.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60'. The system cannot
>   find the file specified.

The project does have a package reference: *PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App"* and this framework includes the missing dll, so I don't know why it's having trouble.

My thoughts are perhaps one of the referenced projects is depending on a different version but I don't see it.

I did try explicitly referencing the package in the top-level project but this made no difference:

```
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions" Version="2.2.0.0" />
```

Here is a current copy of the top-level csproj file:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.2</TargetFramework>
    <AzureFunctionsVersion>v2</AzureFunctionsVersion>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" />
    <PackageReference Include="Base.Core.SharedKernel" Version="1.0.0.23885" />
    <PackageReference Include="FluentValidation" Version="8.4.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="FluentValidation.AspNetCore" Version="8.4.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="MediatR.Extensions.Microsoft.DependencyInjection" Version="7.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions" Version="3.0.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.DurableTask" Version="1.8.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.ServiceBus" Version="3.0.5" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions" Version="1.0.27" />
    <PackageReference Include="Newtonsoft.Json" Version="11.0.2" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\Interfaces.Avaloq.Application\Interfaces.Avaloq.Application.csproj" />
    <ProjectReference Include="..\Interfaces.Avaloq.Common\Interfaces.Avaloq.Common.csproj" />
    <ProjectReference Include="..\Interfaces.Avaloq.Infrastructure\Interfaces.Avaloq.Infrastructure.csproj" />
    <ProjectReference Include="..\Interfaces.Avaloq.Persistence\Interfaces.Avaloq.Persistence.csproj" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Update="host.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
    <None Update="local.settings.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
      <CopyToPublishDirectory>Never</CopyToPublishDirectory>
    </None>
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

**Problems Referencing the Nuget Package**
I can see that assemblies for the "working" package references (such as FluentValidation.dll) can be found in the global packages folder at "C:\Users\bowman_rob_a.nuget\packages". However, the global packages folder does not contain v2.2.0.0 of Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions, it contains lots of versions but skips from 2.1.0 to 3.0.0.

If I run from the package manager console: "install-package Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions -Version 2.2.0" then I get the following error:

> The WriteObject and WriteError methods cannot be called from outside
>   the overrides of the BeginProcessing,  ProcessRecord, and
>   EndProcessing methods, and they can only be called from within the
>   same thread

Despite the error, the package does then appear in the project's packages section of solution explorer. However, it is listed with a strange path "C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\NuGetFallbackFolder\microsoft.extensions.logging.abstractions\2.2.0"

**Problems Referencing the Shared Package**
Because v2.2.0.0 is included in the shared package reference "Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" then I guess the assembly should be pulled from there? The assemblies for shared packages reside in "C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared." There are lots of versions of the shared package 
"Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" but again 2.2.0.0 is skipped, from 2.1.13 to 2.2.4. However, the folder "C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App\2.2.4\Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions.dll" does contain v2.2.0.0 of the dll.

**Version Conflict**
I think the root cause of the problem could be that Azure Functions has a dependency on the nuget package chain: Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions --> Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs --> Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions. The latest version of Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions is 3.0.2 and this leads down to v2.1.0 of Microsoft.Extentions.Logging.Abstractions - this is older than the v2.2.0.0 that's included in the Shared Framework Microsoft.AspNetCore.App. Does anyone know how I can change the version of a Shared Framework that's used by the compiler? I can't find a runtimeconfig.json file anywhere!

**Work Around**
I have been able to make the solution build by removing the Shared Reference from all projects within the solution and adding each required nuget package individually - using the older 2.1.0 versions.

Comment: Have you got any warning in the build process prior to the error?

Comment: Hi friend, what's the template do you choose? As I know when create Azure function project in VS, we can choose different template. And it could be better if you could share more details about what nuget packages your top-level project and other library projects consumed, also what's the target framework of your library projects, .net core or .net standard?

Comment: Hi @LanceLi-MSFT I have now added the top-level csproj

Comment: Hi @AlexBuyny there are no warnings. I have build verbosity set at "detailed"

Comment: @BowmanZhu please see last paragraph in the question

Comment: I'm on .Net 8.0. Solution is to copy the missing DLL into `<function project dir>\bin\Debug\net8.0\bin\`. I have no idea why such copy is needed.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Some info and workaround which may help to resolve the puzzle if someone else meets similar issue.

> It is listed with a strange path "C:\Program
>   Files\dotnet\sdk\NuGetFallbackFolder\microsoft.extensions.logging.abstractions\2.2.0"

[FallBackFolders](https://github.com/NuGet/Home/wiki/%5BSpec%5D-Fallback-package-folders) are something used to share packages across users and machines to reduce risk space.

*They differ from package sources in that the package assets will be referenced directly and will not be copied into the user's packages folder.*

That's why you can't find the package in Global Packages like `C:\Users\xxx\.nuget\packages`.

> For `Version Conflict`

As you mentioned above, the chain of `Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions` is:

```
Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions --> Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs --> Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions(2.1.0)
```

And since you reference the `Microsoft.AspNetCore.App` package, the chain of it:

```
Microsoft.AspNetCore.App(2.2.0) --> Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions(2.2.0)
```

I think this could be the cause of the version conflict.You can remove that package to check if it's another workaround.

**In addition:**

If I create a new Azure Function project in VS16.3.5, we don't need to reference these packages manually:

```
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions" Version="3.0.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.DurableTask" Version="1.8.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.ServiceBus" Version="3.0.5" />
    <PackageReference Include="Newtonsoft.Json" Version="11.0.2" />
```

Since `Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions` depends on these packages, nuget will help us downlaod and reference them.

And I tried several kinds of Azure functions project, but none of them need the `Microsoft.AspNetCore.App` package, so if you don't have specific reason to use that package, you don't need to reference it.

Answer (score 35):

**Make sure none of your packages is above the .NET version of the project.**

In my case the installed version of Microsoft.Extensions.Http was 5.0 while the project was in .NET Core 3.1. As soon as I downgraded the library to 3.1 everything went smoothly.

Source: https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-core-tools/issues/2304

Answer (score 10):

I'm on VS2022 trying to run an httptrigger function of funcapp. I downgraded Microsoft.Extensions.Http from 7.0.0 to 6.0.0 and Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions to 6.0.3. This worked fine.

Comment: Downgrading from 7.0.0 to 6.0.0 Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions & Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Abstractions worked for me too

Comment: This worked for me as well. Love having to do these workarounds because Microsoft can't fully document or test anything.

Comment: I ended up downgrading Microsoft.Extensions.Http from 7.0.0 to 6.0.0 too. My Azure Function is targeting .net6.0 which is supported by Microsoft.Extensions.Http 7.0.0. Seems like a bug.

Comment: This helped me as well.  In my case, I had a timer trigger function with a dependency upon another project containing EF Core.  Downgrading the dependency project to EF Core 6.0.22 enabled me to downgrade Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions to 6.0.3.  This fixed my problems.

Comment: For anyone wondering how to downgrade version of transitive packages, install as root-level packages with Nuget package manager targeting the older version. I also needed to add the property `<TreatWarningsAsErrors>false</TreatWarningsAsErrors>` to `PropertyGroup` in my csproj file to suppress the Nuget warning

Answer (score 7):

I had this problem with v4 of Azure Functions. What solved it for me was editing the .csproj-file and adding
`<_FunctionsSkipCleanOutput>true</_FunctionsSkipCleanOutput>`
to `<PropertyGroup>`.

Comment: yay ! you made my day !

Comment: Please can you provide a reference to a source of this information?

Comment: @AdrianBhagat I am not sure why you would need this? Try it out and see if it works for you. I resolve problems like this by googling my error message but many months later I have no real recollection of what tipped me off to try this approach. I did look at this thread and wanted to share what resolved the issue for me.

Comment: If you are going to post a piece of 'magic' code, it's good practice to show where it came from so people can learn more about it, understand why and how it works, and learn what other unintended effects it may have. It might solve the problem at hand but produce 10 other problems that are unfixable because the developer doesn't know how they were caused.

Answer (score 5):

I just created a new project using .net 6 and ran into this issue.

I installed entity framework nuget packages:

Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools

To support data access into a SQL db.

Both of those libraries defaulted to .net 7 for latest version.

These were the errors I was getting:

```
[2023-01-16T18:15:16.759Z] No job functions found. Try making your job classes and methods public. If you're using binding extensions (e.g. Azure Storage, ServiceBus, Timers, etc.) make sure you've called the registration method for the extension(s) in your startup code (e.g. builder.AddAzureStorage(), builder.AddServiceBus(), builder.AddTimers(), etc.).
[2023-01-16T18:15:16.790Z] The 'Function1' function is in error: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions, Version=7.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60'. The system cannot find the file specified.
```

Even changing the project to .net 7 didn't resolve it, although I wonder if I would have had to update all the nuget packages to 7.  I had to downgrade both of those libraries to .net 6 and it compiled and ran fine.

Regardless, I want to remain on 6 with long term support.  The only nuisance now is that nuget wants to upgrade those two libraries to .net 7 so they show as available for an upgrade.

Comment: I'm having this same issue. I really want to keep EF Core 7 with net6.0 LTS, though, because "EF7 targets .NET 6, and so can be used with either .NET 6 (LTS) or .NET 7." https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-7.0/whatsnew

Comment: Hey - any update on this by chance? I'm running into this myself. I'm starting to pull my hair out here.

Comment: What I did above fixed it for me.  I did find a MS bug report on this as well; so MS is aware of it.

Answer (score 4):

In case of Azure Function V4. Downgrading to `Microsoft.*` 6 version libraries solved the issue.

Support for those dependencies is restricted to 6.0.0. This is a limitation of the in-proc model in V4 running on .NET 6.

The recommendation, if this is a requirement, is to move to the Isolated Model, where .NET dependencies are not restricted/unified.

Answer (score 3):

I encountered this issue after upgrading a Nuget package and then reverting. Had to manually delete all bin and obj folders in the solution before it worked again. Cleaning the solution did not help.

Comment: Worked for me! I had been working on a different branch that was behind on package versions. Started getting this error after switching to a branch with updated packages.

Comment: tx @IAmCoder. Worked for me! In my case it was just a publish on an Azure App

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue on running windows service and had to update config file with newly available version by using redirect technique resolved the issue.

```html
<configuration>
<appSettings />
<runtime>
  <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
    <dependentAssembly>
      <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions" publicKeyToken="adb9793829ddae60" culture="neutral" />
      <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-7.0.0.0" newVersion="7.0.0.0" />
    </dependentAssembly>
    <dependentAssembly>
      <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging" publicKeyToken="adb9793829ddae60" culture="neutral" />
      <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-7.0.0.0" newVersion="7.0.0.0" />
    </dependentAssembly>
    <dependentAssembly>
      <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Extensions.Primitives" publicKeyToken="adb9793829ddae60" culture="neutral" />
      <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-7.0.0.0" newVersion="7.0.0.0" />
    </dependentAssembly>
  </assemblyBinding>
</runtime>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem in the WebJob project that was compiled in Azure DevOps and running with Azure WebApp.

I have managed to solve the problem by changing "Use .Net Core" task version to the last version (3.1.x) in Build pipeline.
[image]

This was the error message :
Unhandled exception. System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=.......'. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (.......)

Answer (score 0):

In my case, VS2022 had added some extra  into the project.csproj file which were trying to reference an older version of a Nuget package of which a later version was already being used.  Once these were remove, the project compiled properly.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error after updating my Azure Functions project to .NET 8. It was still loading .NET 6 packages. Turn out that when I was doing this (January 2024), .NET 8 did not support the in-process model for Functions.

I reverted the project back to .NET 6 until .NET 8 [supports in-process](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/dotnet-isolated-process-guide?tabs=windows#supported-versions)

Another option would be to [migrate your project to the isolated model](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/migrate-dotnet-to-isolated-model?tabs=net8).

Answer (score 0):

I've also encountered the same issue when depending on a project that was using `ILogger` but resolving it from `Microsoft.Extensions.Logging` instead of `Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions` that the main project uses.

The fix is just:

```
- <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging" Version="8.0.0" />
+ <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions" Version="4.2.0" />
```