# Azure Functions dependency collisions with AzureFunctionsTools dependencies

Tags: azure, .net-core, dependencies, azure-functions

I have an Azure Function with a number of dependencies, including `Nuget.Versioning` and `Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions`.

When I try to launch my function (locally or deployed), it results in an error for these files:

```
System.Private.CoreLib: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60'. The system cannot find the file specified.
```

The proper version is in the bin directory, so when I look at the loaded Modules, I can see older versions of these dependencies, which have already been loaded, living in:
`C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Local\AzureFunctionsTools\Releases\3.23.5\cli_x64`

Is there a better way around this than making my nuget dependencies target the same versions of any `AzureFunctionsTools`' dependencies?

Looking randomly through the long list of `AzureFunctionsTools` dependencies there are a number that are quite out of date. My function is using .net core 3.1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try downgrade all the 5.0.0 libraries such as `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer`, `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore` and `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.NetTopologySuitefrom` 5.0 to 3.1.x.

Or, Upgrade it to .Net 5

Please refer [GitHub issue](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-core-tools/issues/2304) and [SO Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58510301/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-microsoft-extensions-logging-abstractions/66696387#66696387) for further references for the similar issue.