# New version to Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.Abstractions 2.2.0

Tags: asp.net-core, nuget-package

In a server log, is showed the following:

2023-08-09T17:40:11.0616272-06:00 0HMSFQU6Q72KK:00000001 [ERR] Connection id ""0HMSFQU6Q72KK"", Request id ""0HMSFQU6Q72KK:00000001"": An unhandled exception was thrown by the application. (560e7d32)
System.IO.FileNotFoundException:
File name: 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.Abstractions, Version=3.1.32.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60'

When checking the packages from the DB to verify the installed packages, I see the Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.Abstractions has 2.2.0 version and is deprecated.

I would like to know which is the new version that corresponds to Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.Abstractions package and where I can find it so that I can install it and correct this issue.

Comment: here's a related issue:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58510301/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-microsoft-extensions-logging-abstractions

Comment: What version of aspnet are you running? I'm not an expert but probably this package is installed with the aspnetcore framework, not typically as a one off package you install yourself - so in this case you may want to just install the required dependency (2.2.0) and if you are so inclined then consider upgrading your application to a newer .net version.